# Combining discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Here is the question:

> $X$ has the distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y$ is such that $P(Y=1) = P(Y=-1) = \frac{1}{2}$
>
> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $Z = XY$. Are $Y$ and $Z$ independent? Are $X$ and $Z$ independent?"

I think that $Z$ has to follow a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution since

$P(Z=z) = P(XY=z) = P(X=z)P(Y=1)+P(X=-z)P(Y=-1) = P(X=z)$ for all $z$

but not sure where to go from here when proving whether or not $Y$ and $Z$ (or $X$ and $Z$) are independent.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intuition is like this: As $|Z|=|XY|=|X|$ you can predict the absolute value of $X$ from knowing $Z$ up to a sign. So $X$ and $Z$ cannot be independent. On the other hand, as $P(X=x) = P(X=-x)$ for all $x$, from knowing $Z$ you cannot tell whether $Y$ was positive or negative, i.e. both results are equally likely, i.e. $Z$ and $Y$ are independent.

As a proof you could show that

- $P(|X|<1,|Z|>1) = 0 \neq P(|X|<1)P(|Z|>1)$ contradicting independence of $X,Z$.
- Using your results on $P(Z<z)$ you can show that $$P(Y=1,Z<z)=\dots=P(Y=1)P(Z<z)$$ and $$P(Y=-1,Z<z)=\dots=P(Y=-1)P(Z<z)$$
  showing that $Y,Z$ are independent.